# У меня есть код бота на Python, как можно добавить туда клавиатуру

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

Есть бот для вк написанный на Python, хочу после команды "Привет", вызывалась клавиатура, но не понимаю, как можно это реализовать.

Вот код:

````
import time
import random
import json

#Токен
token = "943c0971e8904c9e2751549113df1c78378f6e6bb739ce4b8b0aa9b2d8236f884ce9b7e678652df86a8a3"

#Регестрация
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()

#Список приветствий
greetings = {'привет', 'здравствуй','ку','хелло','прив','начать','хай'}
#Команды
commands = ['случайное тз']

#Основной цикл
while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            #Ответ на приветствия
            if body.lower() in greetings:
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            #Случайное ТЗ
            elif body.lower() in commands[0]:
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Cкоро тут будут ТЗ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            #Неправильная команда
            else:
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Не понял тебя!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)```
````

Comment: расширьте описание вопроса.что вы подразумеваете под 'клавиатура' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клавиатура отправляется как сообщение пользователю. При этом текст у сообщения тоже должен быть

Для удобства можете использовать модуль [vk_api](https://pypi.org/project/vk-api/)

Сама клавиатура - объект `vk_api.keyboard.Keyboard`

На гитхабе есть прекрасный [пример](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/keyboard.py) использования клавиатуры

**Тем более не советую светить свой токен в вопросах**

Comment: токен не действителен) А так спасибо)

Comment: @YFrite если ответ решил проблему вы можете принять его, что бы не висел как не отвеченный. Не за что)